# Magento 2 : Multiple shipping address for every items of an order

Tags: magento2.2.2

Currently, I am using Magento 2.2 version I need customize the checkout page for add multiple shipping addresses like I want to separate shipping address for every item of an order.

Exp. I have added 3 different products to the cart and on the checkout page, I want to separate shipping address for each product.

Please give me your suggestion. Is it possible or not?

Comment: Check the answer & give feedback

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to just enable **Multishipping** checkout feature

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osNFPLC-_ME

Comment: I need add multiple shipping address for every item of an order like I have A, B, and C three items in cart. Now I want to add different address to each item...

Comment: Yes you are right for registered customers only but I need for guest customers also. So have you any suggestion about that

Comment: Multishipping checkout feature should work also for guest users

Comment: yes. Is it possible?

Comment: Did anybody manage to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

overwritten  on this function on module-quate/Model/quote.php

```
public function getShippingAddressesItems()
    {
        if ($this->shippingAddressesItems !== null) {
            return $this->shippingAddressesItems;
        }
        $items = [];
        $addresses = $this->getAllAddresses();
        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            //echo 'test1'.count($address->getAllItems());

            foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getProduct()->getIsVirtual()) {
                    $items[] = $item;
                    continue;
                }

                $item->setCustomerAddressId($address->getCustomerAddressId());
                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
        $this->shippingAddressesItems = $items;
        // echo 'test'.count($items);
        // exit;
        return $items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this default setting
Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Multishipping Setting